# Adding column based on data in other data frame

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to calculate the average exam score of each student and add this as a new column to a data frame:

```
library(dplyr)

my_students <- c("John", "Lisa", "Sam")
student_exam <- c("John", "Lisa", "John", "John")
score_exam <- c(7, 6, 7, 6)

students <- as.data.frame(my_students)
scores <- as.data.frame(student_exam)
scores <- cbind(scores, score_exam)

new_frame <- students %>% mutate(avg_score = (scores %>% filter(student_exam == my_students) %>% mean(score_exam)))
```

But the code above gives the following error:

```
Error in Ops.factor(student_examn, my_students) : 
  level sets of factors are different
```

I assume it has to do with filter`(student_exam == my_students)`. How would I do this in dplyr?

Comment: Not very clear what the `filter` tries to do. All your students have a score in your example. Something like this would work in your case: `df = data.frame(student_exam, score_exam);

df %>%
  group_by(student_exam) %>%
  mutate(avg_score = mean(score_exam)) %>%
  ungroup()`

Comment: @AntoniosK this would remove Sam from the result if I am correct. I need Sam to remain. If it has no grades for a student it should just say NA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure you define two data frames with matching column named "name". You can then use group_by and summarize to group scores by student and summarize the average for each student. This solution has a warning that is telling you that you should be aware that not every student in your class has an average exam score. As a result, Sam's average score is NA.

```r
library(dplyr)

my_students <- c("John", "Lisa", "Sam")
student_exam <- c("John", "Lisa", "John", "John")
score_exam <- c(7, 6, 7, 6)

students <- data.frame("name" = as.character(my_students))
scores <- data.frame("name" = as.character(student_exam), "score" = score_exam)


avg_scores <- scores %>%
  group_by(name) %>%
  summarize(avgScore = mean(score)) %>%
  right_join(students)
```

Comment: I would like to keep Sam in the resulting data frame. I assume this removes him? Id'like to just have it say NA if there are no scores for Sam.

Comment: @RuudVerhoef that is the result of this approach.